# How to convert between TimeSpan and DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

A bit silly question, but I find myself not sure how to answer it.

```
Timespan ts = (DateTime1 - DateTime2).TotalMinutes
```

Suppose I know `ts` and `DateTime2`, how can I find `DateTime1`?

Comment: Add `ts` to `DateTime2`? `var DateTime1 = DateTime2.Add(ts);`

Comment: By the way, `TotalMinutes` property returns `double` which is not implicitly casting to `TimeSpan`  so, your code _probably_ won't even compile as such.

Comment: This is not "converting" between a `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`. You're just adding a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime`, or retrieving the previous operand in a subtraction operation between two `DateTime`s that yielded a `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `TimeSpan` to a date

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime1 - DateTime2;

DateTime1 = DateTime2 + ts;
```

Note that I removed the `TotalMinutes`, because it returns a `double`, not a `TimeSpan`.

If you want to work with minutes, you can write

```
double minutes = (DateTime1 - DateTime2).TotalMinutes;

DateTime1 = DateTime2 + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
```

Note that the minutes contain the seconds and fractions of seconds as decimals. If you only need the full minutes, you can get them with:

```
int fullMinutes = (int)Math.Floor(minutes);
```

Comment: Beat me too it! 

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compile.

Example:

```
 DateTime DateTime1 = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime DateTime2 = DateTime1.AddMinutes(-10);
 var ts = (DateTime1 - DateTime2).TotalMinutes;  //  ts is a double

 DateTime DateTime3 = DateTime1 + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(ts);
```